# Tensorflow Lite Micro package in Keil custom MCU platform

Tags: c, compiler-errors, microcontroller, tensorflow-lite, keil

I have tried to use tflite default package in Keil MDK environment, but I am facing some compiling problems.

[project code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ar8uh.png)

My Device: Armv8-M Mainline based device

My TFlite runtime environment:

[runtime environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1z1qO.png)

There are hundreds of errors existed.

error type1

[error: use of undeclared identifier 'EAFNOSUPPORT'/.../...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5keVW.png)

error type2

[error: use of undeclared identifier 'errno'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOEPb.png)

What's maybe going wrong?

I tried to compile the package in an empty project with the same environment settings, and it could be compiled instead of such as errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by disabling the redefined symbol in ROM.lib file.